# How to do an if-else in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Hi i've tried using the Switch and Boolean Math to no avail. How do i do this type of logic? i want an optional input for a profile curve, if no input is given then just use the default Curve Circle node i have inside the node group. Do i need to code this and how?

[image]

**UPDATE**: thank you for sharing the link it did help me get the working setup.

[image]

Comment: @Gorgious I don't think it does.  I just voted not to close this because it's not that the OP wants to know true/false, it's that they want to select between two different nodes to feed to one node based on true/false -- the sort of thing you do with the fac of a mixRGB node in a shader.

Comment: oh i tried the link, it actually did help me, thank you guys for your time and help!

Comment: @MartyFouts yeah you're right the second part (the switch node) was not part of the linked duplicate, but the "evaluate if an input contains any geometry" part is pretty much the same. Anyways I think linking the two as duplicates is a right course of action, because now both Q&As are linked together and curious people can stumble upon it :) cheers

Comment: @Gorgious: If the OP is ok with that (and he said he is) I'm OK with that.